# Rstudio / blogdown: how to deploy on your own server (apache)

Tags: r, apache, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I have a small **hugo** site that I am using as front matter to surveys. I would like to gather the workflow entirely in Rstudio. At present I edit the templates and content pages in a text editor and then use rsync to push the updates to apache webserver (both locally on the dev machine and via SSH). My question is - can I edit my website through `Rstudio / blogdown` and use rsync from within Rstudio?

Below is example of rsync that I use on server:

```
$ hugo && sudo rsync --chown=http:http  -avz --delete --exclude lime  public/ /srv/http/
```

For me it is not a problem to kep going like this, but I am very interested in keeping things simple/automated and in one place as much as possible.  I will need to teach other people to keep updating the site and while they can press `knit` in rstudio, if I tell them to open a terminal, there may be a problem.

Comment: Maybe put rsync into an Rscript and run the script in rstudio?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will investigate it. I will probably end up making a function for this, my only concern is the portability between linux and windows; I will need to look into that.